# Eclipse doesn't work with Genymotion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, genymotion

I use:

- Windows 8.1
- ADT Eclipse 22.3.0-887826
- Genymotion 2.5.4
- Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.4

In the ADT environment, when I click the Genymotion Virtual Device Manager button, it reminds me to set up the path where I installed Genymotion. I set it right and when I click the button again, Genymotion doesn't show up.

The Eclipse console gives me these messages:

> Output file: C:\Users\lenovo.genymotion-eclipse.log
>
> Loading Genymotion library
>
> Genymotion directory: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
>
> Trying to initialize engine
>
> Invalid path: VBoxManage
>
> Initialize Engine: failed

I just can't get this done, does anyone have the same problem? Can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: set up path as   C:\Program Files\Genymobile

Comment: You can directly open GenyMotion from its launcher icon and eclipse will detect it automatically and display it on online devices.

Comment: thank you guys! your advice help me a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Try manually connect the Genymotion with ADB:

1. Go to `<SDK location>/platform-tools/`. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd> and select *open command window here*.
2. Restart Genymotion emulator and wait until finish its startup.
3. In the command prompt window, enter:

   `adb kill-server`

   `adb start-server`
4. Then, run your app from eclipse. If doesn't work, run again step 3.